# Wordpress Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: wordpress

I have such a problem in wordpress. When I try to publish post it says Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xxx/domains/colibrilab.net/public_html/mysite/wp-content/plugins/events-manager/classes/em-calendar.php:1) in /home/xxx/domains/colibrilab.net/public_html/mysite/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 877.

And in line 877 there is

`header("Location: $location", true, $status);`

And it works normally on localhost and the problem is only when I put it live.

What can be the problem?

Comment: is there any other notice/warning before this one?

Comment: noo.., this is the one  :/

Comment: the problem can not come from the `/wp-includes` folder because those are functions of the system. this must be some error with `events-manager` plugin, check where it sendes the headers and how and add it to the question please :)

Comment: that warning means that there is some sort of output before line 877. the output could be anything, a warning, a notice, or even a whitespace. You have to figure out what is producing that output

Comment: ok... but I don think the problem is events-manager plugin cause the same error appears when  i use wp-redirect or header(Location:...) in other plugins.

Answer (score 0):

```
function app_output_buffer() {
    ob_start();
} // soi_output_buffer
add_action('init', 'app_output_buffer');
```

Add this code in your function.php